# React Native app for android when moved to background shows white screen?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

When I move my `React native` app to background irrespective on which screen I am on, it shows white screen instead of the screen I should be in? I am not talking about the white splash screen.
This issue happens only on android and not on iOS

https://preview.redd.it/yhalbullg3b61.jpg?width=720&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=a690d3470b7923d8de64d38fa335d86257fd6612

I am using `React Navigation`. I am not even sure what code to post or where to look for debugging.
I also tried with release mode `apk` but the issue persists for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not `React-Native` specific issue. I have set `FLAG_SECURE` in android for one of my Native module. Removing it resolved this issue